# Installing Trusty packages in Saucy

Tags: upgrade, software-installation

The version of `yate` in Saucy is giving me issues with `pulseaudio` and I wanted to install a newer version, so I installed all the required debs from trusty to make `yate-qt4` work. I have not run into any issues thus far and all seems to be working well, but will this give me issues with upgrading later on?

Answer (score 1):

Since Trusty immediately follows Saucy, you should not have any problems upgrading *if* you upgrade to trusty (first). Even if you want to upgrade to the u-series, do not skip the upgrade step to Trusty, to get your system fully “in sync” again.

But yes, running “mixed distributions” is what people are doing all the time.

In Debian, running a mixed stable/oldstable or stable/testing or stable/testing/unstable or stable/unstable system is supported, but not mixing oldstable with testing for example (skipping one distribution).

In Ubuntu, mixing distributions is normally supported either version X and X+1, or version X=LTS and X+4=LTS+1, since you are allowed to directly upgrade from one LTS to the next one. (On the other hand, since there are 4 full Ubuntu releases between LTS releases, mixing packages like that will be much less likely to succeed due to updated dependencies (libraries, for example) and whole-system changes).

It is much safer to install packages from an older version on a newer system, than to install select packages from a newer version on an older system. Generally, one uses backports (either official or PPA) for that.